# Group results in Jolt

Tags: jolt

I am trying to group some data in arrays based on a json field.

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Cash",
    "Value1": "668131AA3",
    "ParentId": "87984E01",
    "CashId": "6688E582",
    "StockId": null
  },
  {
    "Type": "Stock",
    "Value1": "668131AA3",
    "ParentId": "87984E01",
    "CashId": "1FD714A9",
    "StockId": "1FD714A9"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Stock",
    "Value1": "668131AA3",
    "ParentId": "87984E01",
    "CashId": "0635B045",
    "StockId": "0635B045"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Cash",
    "Value1": "668131AA3",
    "ParentId": "87984E01",
    "CashId": "47E65472",
    "StockId": null
  }
]
```

And the desired output is:

```
    "Value1": "668131AA3",
    "ParentId": "87984E01",
    "CashPayouts" : [ 
        {"CashId": "6688E582"},
        {"CashId": "87984E01"}
    ],
    "StockPayouts" : [ 
       {"StockId": "1FD714A9","CashId": "1FD714A9"},
       {"StockId": "0635B045","CashId": "0635B045"}
     ]
}
```

Basically, if the `Type=Cash`, `CashId` field should be grouped in `CashPayouts` array. For `Type=Stock`, group two fields in `StockPayouts` array.

Is it possible to do this transformation in Jolt? If it is true, how?

Thanks,
Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be completed example:

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Value1": "Value1",
        "ParentId": "ParentId",
        "Type": {
          "Stock": {
            "@(2)": {
              "CashId": "t.StockPayouts[&4].CashId",
              "StockId": "t.StockPayouts[&4].StockId"
            }
          },
          "Cash": {
            "@(2)": {
              "CashId": "t.CashPayouts[&4].CashId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls",
      "Value1": "=firstElement(@(1,Value1))",
      "ParentId": "=firstElement(@(1,ParentId))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Value1": "Value1",
      "ParentId": "ParentId",
      "t": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Magda, it is almost done but null values are present in the array:

{
  "Value1" : "668131AA3",
  "ParentId" : "87984E01",
  "CashPayouts" : [ {
    "CashId" : "6688E582"
  }, null, null, {
    "CashId" : "47E65472"
  } ],
  "StockPayouts" : [ null, {
    "CashId" : "1FD714A9",
    "StockId" : "1FD714A9"
  }, {
    "CashId" : "0635B045",
    "StockId" : "0635B045"
  } ]
}

According https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception. I will verify

Comment: You are right, now I correct it. I should pack arrays with nulls to the "t" array, and than recursivelySquashNulls works.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Why do you have to do another operation to remove nulls?

Comment: It is because I have to pack two arrays into t object firstly than remove nulls and at the end I have to unpack arrays from t object. I think that to use recursivelySquashNulls, propably instead of packing it into t object I could use recursivelySquashNulls twice on each array separately.